# Missing files during compilation of ogl program

Tags: ubuntu, opengl

I have been following this ( http://opengl.datenwolf.net/gltut/html/index.html ) tutorial on opengl but i cannot build the first example. The guide suggests using premake as an executable but i had to install it on my ubuntu machine to get it to work. I searched around and installed several ogl libraries like freeglut and glew. but i dont understand what the error is. Here is what the terminal says :

```
 hammad@hamlet:~/graphicsprogramming/gltut-master/Tut 01 Hello Triangle$ make config=release
 Linking Tut 01 Main
 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lglutil
 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lfreeglut
 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lglmesh
 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lglimg
 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lglload
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 Makefile:85: recipe for target 'Tut 01 Main' failed
 make: *** [Tut 01 Main] Error 1
 hammad@hamlet:~/graphicsprogramming/gltut-master/Tut 01 Hello Triangle$ make
 Linking Tut 01 Main
 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lglutilD
 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lfreeglutD
 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lglmeshD
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 Makefile:85: recipe for target 'Tut 01 MainD' failed
 make: *** [Tut 01 MainD] Error 1
 hammad@hamlet:~/graphicsprogramming/gltut-master/Tut 01 Hello Triangle$ make config=debug
 Linking Tut 01 Main
 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lglutilD
 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lfreeglutD
 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lglmeshD
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 Makefile:85: recipe for target 'Tut 01 MainD' failed
 make: *** [Tut 01 MainD] Error 1
```

Comment: The libraries you reference seem to come from the `glsdk` mentioned in one of the premake files. Did the premake step work? If so, it should have downloaded and unpacked glsdk somewhere.

Comment: Yes i have downloaded and moved the glsdk into the tutorial folder. This gl sdk was not meant to be installed. Without moving it, the premake step would fail.

Comment: You'll have to inspect the generated `Makefile`s then. More specifically the `-L` options passed to your compiler. They should point into the glsdk directory somewhere. I'm a bit puzzled by your statement that you had to download it manually though, from what I can see `premake` should download glsdk itself.